# How can I use INTERVAL() to measure elapsed time?

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

Could anyone help me figure out how to check which loop is faster - FOR or REPEAT, using Etime and interval function?

```
do:
    etime(yes).
    repeat i = 1 to 5:
       display '123'.
    end. 
    end1 = etime.
    display "etime for repeat block" end1 - start1. 
end.
```

Instead of using end1-start1 I would like to use interval function to find the elapsed time. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare datetime variables and use the "now" function.

```
define variable dt1 as datetime no-undo.
define variable dt2 as datetime no-undo.

dt1 = now.

pause 3.

dt2 = now.

display interval( dt2, dt1, "milliseconds" ).
```

Place the code that you want to test where the PAUSE statement is.

(You will need many, many more than 5 iterations to get a meaningful result.)

Comment: It is traditional to click the upward pointing arrow as a way of saying "thanks" and to click on the "correct" button when the answer "works".